# CMenu Styling in Yii

Tags: php, css, yii

I am styling my CMenu according to my theme. Below is my code.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="nav">
<ul id="navlist" class="sf-menu clearfix">

<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
'items'=>array(
array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
array('label'=>'Registration','url'=>array('/registration'),
'items'=>array(
array('label'=>'Registration','url'=>array('/registration')),
array('label'=>'Abc Registration','url'=>array('/registration/abc')),
),'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/user/user/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
),
));

?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The generated html is shown  below

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul id="navlist" class="sf-menu clearfix">

   <ul id="yw1">


  <li><a href="/mysite/site/contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="/mysite/registration">Registration</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/mysite/registration">Registration</a></li>
  <li><a href="/mysite/registration/abc">Abc Registration</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/mysite/user/user/login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>                
  </ul>
  </nav>
 <!-- Navigation -->
```

The problem is Yii generated id is yw1..i want to change the it as 'navlist'.How to customise the CMenu like that?

Edit

I tried by setting css class in html options also. But it is only setting class,not Id. So its giving the same result only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CMenu` extends `CWidget`. Use [`CWidget.id`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#id-detail):

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'id'=> 'navlist',
    'items'=>array(
        ...
```

Comment: How to give a separate ul class for the registration item since it involves submenu.Any idea?

Comment: Check [`items`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#items-detail) property, there is an item option named `submenuOptions`. You will need to set it explicitly for each one of the items.

Answer (score 5):

just add an `id` attribute in your widget

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'id'=> 'navlist',
```

**i am not sure but try this**

```
    array('label'=>'Item1', 'url'=>"#",
     'linkOptions'=>array('id'=>'myId1'),
'submenuOptions'=>array('id'=>'myId'),
```

Comment: How to give a separate ul class for the registration item since it involves submenu.Any idea?

Comment: @DencyGB same way as you give for main nav. add 'id'=>'yourid' before items